# How to delete similar pair values in dataframe?

Tags: pandas

Input:

```
   Source   Target    
      A        A          
      A        B          
      A        C          
      B        A          
      B        C          
      C        A          
      C        B  
      B        B
```

Output:

```
   Source   Target    
      A        A          
      A        B          
      A        C               
      B        C
```

The result I want is that when there is structure for columns like

```
   Source   Target    
      B        A          
      A        B
```

, it will delete one of the rows( either `B A` or `A B` ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `sorted` and get duplicates by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` invert boolean mask:

```
cols = ['Source','Target']
df = df[~df[cols].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()]
print (df)
  Source Target
0      A      A
1      A      B
2      A      C
4      B      C
7      B      B
```

Another solution with [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
cols = ['Source','Target']
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols], axis=1), columns=cols).duplicated()]
print (df)
  Source Target
0      A      A
1      A      B
2      A      C
4      B      C
7      B      B
```

Another solution if only 2 columns with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.apply(sorted, axis=1).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
  Source Target
0      A      A
1      A      B
2      A      C
4      B      C
7      B      B
```